# Plotting multiple cruves on a single XY scatter plot from different sheets

Tags: vba

I have 10 sheets. Eachs sheet has x-values and y-values which I want to plot in ONE xy-scatter plot. I wrote the code below. It works for one sheet but not for all the sheets. Additionally, I dont know how to name each series with a specific name (it can be references to a particular cell in each sheet). Kindly note that on each sheet; x-values, y-value are exactly starting and end in the same cell reference. Same is true for series name cell reference.

```
Sub PlotPcVsSwAllSheets()

Dim ch As Chart
Dim Sw As Range
Dim Pcres As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
    
Set ch = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatter).Chart

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set ws.Sw = ws.Range("C23", Range("C23").End(xlDown))
    Set ws.Pcres = ws.Range("AA23", Range("AA23").End(xlDown))
    With ch
        ch.SetSourceData Source:=Union(ws.Sw, ws.Pcres)
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add each series one by one.

```vb
Sub PlotPcVsSwAllSheets()

    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim Sw As Range
    Dim Pcres As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set ch = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatter).Chart
    'remove any series added by default
    Do While ch.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
        ch.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Set Sw = ws.Range("C23", ws.Range("C23").End(xlDown))
        Set Pcres = Sw.EntireRow.Columns("AA") 'safer
        With ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = Sw
            .Values = Pcres
            .Name = ws.Range("A3").Value 'for example
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working. It plots for sheet1 but on next sheet, it gives error message (Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed). The error comes when executing Set Sw = ws.Range("C23", ws.Range("C23").End(xlDown)) line. Additionally after executing AddChart line, it takes plots other available data in the sheet

Comment: Couple of edits above - this worked for me.